# what is the equivalent of watchEffect in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a VueJS 2 component, I populate a props variable when the component is loaded.

```
  created() {
    this.events = null
    Service.getEvents()
      .then(response => {
        this.events = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
      })
  }
}
```

I need to reload the component with "events" props when a next page  is clicked. I saw a VueJS 3 tutorial, where the props variable is reloaded using the watchEffect method (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watcheffect)

What is the equivalent of this functionality in VueJS 2?

I tried to use the watch() method for this variable, but that causes an infinite recursion because the "events" object is changed inside the method.

```
//Error - recusrsion
watch: {
    events() {
    this.events = null
    Service.getEvents()
    .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data)
              this.events = response.data
            })
    .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.response)
            })
        }
    },
```

How can we reload the events in the same page when user clicks a button/link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your code `this.events` mean the variable of watch...

so it cause recursion.

if you want to add event on click next page,

then add `@click=` event props on component of next page props

Comment: @jinseok-oh what should I do to reload the events data in the same page/component?

Comment: could you describe more detail ?

Comment: create method for reload event and attach function on to @click=

Answer (score 1):

watch in the options api receives the old and the new value:

```
watch: {
    event: function (oldEventData, newEventData) {
        console.log(newEventData) // do something with new event data
    }
},
```